# can not create requirements.txt file

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, requirements.txt

i have a `virtualenv` called `alpha` but after upgrading my ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 19, now i cant install any `python package` into my `virtualenv`, basically i cant use `pip3` command. whenever i use pip3 command i got this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'` **(i have tried: sudo apt install python3-dist-utils but its not working)**. Now because i cant use `pip3 command` i cant create `requirements.txt` file. i want to remove my old `alpha` virtualenv and want to install new one and install all the dependencies using `requirements.txt` file, but i can't do that because i can't create `requirements.txt`. How do i solve this problem ?

**Edit**

Because i have so many libraries installed in my virtualenv(i cant even remember them). first i want to recover all the dependency information's and then want to install new one. **I CANT JUST REMOVE THE VIRTUALENV FIRST**.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-distutils

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: Also, Pipfile is actually recommended over a requirements file

Comment: tried: ```sudo apt-get install python3-distutils``` its saying: **python3-distutils is already the newest version (3.7.5-1build1)**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no package like `dist-utils`, you are looking for `python3-dist-utils`.

Comment: yep ! i have tried ```python3-dist-utils``` . that was my typo. its giving me same error, **can not import name dist**

Comment: Maybe you have to create new virtualenv after you installed dist-utils.